# ARM Template - Creating dependency between two nested templates

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

**I have two nested deployments:**

**One** for resource group A which deploys a managed identity.

**Second** for resource group B which deploys a Keyvault and sets an access policy to the ManagedIdentity in resource group A.

---

**I would like to have the nested deployment of the resource group B to be dependent on the nested deployment of resource group A.**
(My main template is deploying to resource group C)

---

**I have tried:**

```
"dependsOn": [
                "[variables('resourceGroupADeploymentName')]"
              ],
```

But I keep failing on:
The Resource 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/managedIdentityA' under resource group 'A' was not found.

After a while I see the ManagedIdentityA created in resource group A - so it means the dependsOn did not work and the resourceGroupB deployment did not wait for ResourceGroupA deployment.

I also tried using dependsOn resourceId but it did not work. (and also adding the dependsOn to the actual KeyVault resource deployment within ResourceGroupB)

---

**Any idea how can I have a resource from resource group B dependent on resource from resource group A?**

---

This is my ARM Template for resourceGroupB:

```
{
      "name": "resourceGroupBDeploymentName",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceDeploymentApiVersion')]",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('B')]",
      "subscriptionId": "[parameters('S')]",
      "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('resourceGroupADeploymentName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
              "name": "[concat(parameters('deploymentKvName'), '/add')]",
              "apiVersion": "[variables('kvApiVersion')]",
              "properties": {
                "accessPolicies": [
                  {
                    "tenantId": "[parameters('S')]",
                    "objectId": "[reference(variables('ManagedIdentityResourceGroupA'), '2018-11-30').principalId]",
                    "permissions": {
                        "keys": [],
                        "secrets": [],
                        "certificates": [
                            "Get"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
              }
            }           
            }          
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

This is my ARM Template for resourceGroupA:

```
{
      "name": "[variables('ManagedIdentityResourceGroupA')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('resourceDeploymentApiVersion')]",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('A')]",
      "subscriptionId": "[parameters('S')]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "name": "[variables('ManagedIdentityResourceGroupA')]",
              "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
              "apiVersion": "2018-11-30",
              "tags": {},
              "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way around that yet. Dependencies only work in the same resource gruop. you can use deployment script resource to run a script that would check the status and that can act as a dependsOn

Comment: I was sure there should be a way to create dependencies between two resources in different resource groups (whic are not in the parent deployment but in nested ones). Can you please refer me to deployment script resource you mentioned?

Comment: did you google it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template